# Appending a file in NodeJS in order to generate radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, radio-button

I just found a solution about incrementing/appending radio buttons with JQuery over on a thread I created earlier today.

I have a simple form as the index.html:
[:8080/index.html Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJurx.png)

Once the user hits submit, they get this:
[:8080/names.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI5hO.png)

Clicking the remove button and selecting Confirm or Decline doesn't do anything.

Please view my comment on the bottom for more explanation (I can't post more than 2 links/pictures in a post).

Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: I have simulated what I wanted in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fvpLS/7.

Of course, over time, as more people will "register", the longer the list of names: https://puu.sh/x40Ug/bdb936252a.png. 

The reason I wanted this solution up and running is because I am trying to reproduce the part about incrementing radio buttons over on NodeJS. Here is the code about appending a file in NodeJS that I got: https://puu.sh/x411l/db0cdb7eca.png

(I replied to myself, because I can't post more than 2 links/pictures in a post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out!
I added: `"$(document).ready(function(){"`

so that it executes the increment whenever the page loads!

Thanks David!